# Exception logging in ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, error-logging

Currently I log exceptions as follows-

```
 public ActionResult Login()
 {
        try
        {
            throw new Exception("test");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogException(ex);
        }  
        return View();
    }
```

I can get a clear & detail information about the exception from `LogException()` method here. See below-

```
Created on: 27-Dec-2016, 06.34.33 PM
Type: System.Exception
Error Description: test 
Source File: ...\Controllers\LoginController.cs
Method: Login
Line: 20
Column: 17
```

I tried the same method in -

```
public class MyCustomAttribute : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        Exception ex = filterContext.Exception;            
        LogException(ex)
    }
}

public class MyCustomAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
         Exception ex = filterContext.Exception;            
         LogException(ex)
    }
}
```

I also tried overloading OnException method-

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
        public BaseController() {}

        protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            Exception ex = filterContext.Exception;
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;

            LogException(ex);
        }
}
```

In all three abose cases I am getting no information about Source File, Method, Line and Column-

```
 Created on: 27-Dec-2016, 06.44.45 PM
 Type: System.Exception
 Error Description: test 
 Source File: 
 Method: <BeginInvokeAction>b__1e
 Line: 0
 Column: 0
```

This is my method to log exception-

```
       public static void Create(Exception exception, String rootDirectoryPath)
        {
            try
            {
                StackTrace st = new StackTrace(exception, true);                 
                StackFrame frame = st.GetFrame(st.FrameCount - 1);
                string fileName = frame.GetFileName();
                string methodName = frame.GetMethod().Name;
                int line = frame.GetFileLineNumber();
                int col = frame.GetFileColumnNumber();

                //Other code .....
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //do nothing.               
            }
        }
```

My question is, is it possible to retrieve Source File, Method, Line and Column information from those three cases?

I would not like to handle exceptions by writing `try .. catch..` every time.

I have heard about ELMAH & Log4Net. But not sure whether those library able to  supply my desired information from exceptions.

Sorry for the long question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of [Coderr](https://coderr.io) which also takes care of tracking exceptions for you.

the problem with your solution is that the exception filter (and the ASP.NET framework calls to invoke it) will be part of the stack trace, thus getting frames from the stack trace object wont work.

Also note that if the .PDB file is not included when you put your web site in production you wont get file numbers.

The most common approach is just to log `exception.ToString()` which will include line numbers in the stack trace (if there is a PDB file).

Why do you want to use your custom approach?

Answer (score 0):

You are reinventing the wheel as [ELMAH](https://www.nuget.org/packages/elmah) will do the job just fine. Did you give it a try? Just a Nuget package and some configuration to be fully set.

You can read more about it from [Scot Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ELMAHErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlersForASPNETAndMVCToo.aspx) or [read the tutorial](http://blog.elmah.io/elmah-tutorial/).

Comment: Well, If I would like to do it in my way other than ELMAH?

Comment: Then I would recommend you to check their source code to see how they are doing and replicate in your code: https://github.com/elmah/Elmah